# axios.all shows a function as undefined

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js, axios, referenceerror

Hey guys I am using axios.all within my vuejs and javascript code. But when the page is loaded none of the content can be seen and within the chrome console it says:

```
[nuxt]Error while initializing app ReferenceError: getAllTicketGroups is not defined.
```

I am not sure why this is happening.

Below is the JavaScript code that I am using.

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
    layout: 'Account',
    components:{
        'accountTickets' : TicketsAccountTickets
    },

    data(){
        return{
            allTickets: [],
            event_id  : this.event_id,
            getTickets:{
                seeTickets:{
                    event_id : this.event_id
                }
            },
            findTickets: {},
            eventsId: [],
        }
    },

    mounted:{
        getAllTicketGroups: function(){
            return axios.get('https://api.ticketpass.co/tickets',{
                headers:{
                    "Content-Type" : "application/json",
                    "Accept" : "application/json"
                }
            })
            .then(response =>{
                if(response.status === 200){
                    for(let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++){
                        console.log(response.data[i].event_id);
                        this.allTickets.push({
                            "some_id" : response.data[i].id,
                            "event_id" : response.data[i].event_id,
                            "created" : response.data[i].created,
                            "code" : response.data[i].code,
                            "user_id" : response.data[i].user_id
                        })

                        this.getTickets.seeTickets = {
                        "event_id" : response.data[i].event_id
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        },

        getEventId: function(){
            if(!(response.data[i].event_id in this.findTickets) && this.eventsId.indexOf(response.data[i].event_id) == -1){
                return axios.get('https://api.ticketpass.co/event/' + response.data[i].event_id,{
                    headers:{
                        "Content-Type" : "application/json",
                        "Accept" : "application/json",
                        "Authorization" : this.accessToken
                    }
                })
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    this.findTickets[response.data.id] = response.data;
                })
                console.log("Data Added");
            }else{
                console.log("IN Object");
            }
            console.log(this.findTickets);
        }
    }
}

axios.all([getAllTicketGroups(), getEventId()])
.then(axios.spread(function (list, got){
    console.log(list);
    console.log(got);
}));
</script>
```

If someone could please help it would be much appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Vue structure and some logic parts are incorrect:

1. You should rename your `mounted` section to `methods` I think it's typo.
2. You can not call methods with way you provide in your question, place your initial request to `mounted` or `created` hook and invoke methods on `this` :

   ```
   mounted() {
      axios.all([this.getAllTicketGroups(), this.getEventId()])
         .then(axios.spread(function (list, got){
            console.log(list);
            console.log(got);
         }));
   }
   ```
3. Also you reference some `response` variable in the top of `getEventId` method which will always be **undefined** because it is not declared.
4. Also you does not see anything in console after main request finished successfully  because you don't return anything in `getAllTicketGroups` and `getEventId` "thens". So you should re-return your response in `then` to make `console.log` display your response.

UPDATE

5. Request chaining for tickets, quick example:

   ```
    mounted() {

      this.getAllTicketGroups().then((response) => {
          let requests = [];
          this.allTickets.forEach((t) => {
             requests.push(this.getEventId(t.event_id));
          });
          return axios.all(requests);
      });
    }
    ...
    getEventId: function(event_id){
       if(!(event_id in this.findTickets) && 
         this.eventsId.indexOf(event_id) == -1){
           return axios.get('https://api.ticketpass.co/event/' + event_id,{
               headers:{
                   "Content-Type" : "application/json",
                   "Accept" : "application/json",
                   "Authorization" : this.accessToken
               }
           })
           .then(response => {
               console.log(response.data);
               this.findTickets[response.data.id] = response.data;
           })
           console.log("Data Added");
       }else{
           console.log("IN Object");
       }
       console.log(this.findTickets);
   }
   ```

Comment: The response.data[i].event_id is connected to an API to get details for an event. So how can I reference it?

Comment: I think you should call `getEventId` for each ticket after `getAllTicketGroups`. You should iterate over `this.allTickets` instead of undefined `response.data`.

Comment: @AadilHafesji I added example of chaining requests for tickets to my answer.

Comment: I have used your code, but the issue is that "requests.push(this.getEventId(t.event_id));" is saying that it needs ':' instead of the dot

Comment: @AadilHafesji I hope you use code without `...` :) it will be better to see all your updated code I do not see some error in my code.

Comment: This is a jsfiddle with the updated JavaScript code. Hope it helps. https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/163039/

Comment: @AadilHafesji in line `this.allTickets.forEach((t) => {` you don't add `>` symbol and add `this` to `getAllTicketGroups()`. Also remove old axios.all(...) request in the bottom.